Amend name servers in Microsoft 365
Our domain is managed by AWS Route53 and Emails are hosted via Microsoft 365
We were using AWS Account (say AWSX) for a long time. When you created Microsoft 365 (M365) account, it used the nameservers of AWSX. We then added MX, TXT, CNAME in the AWSX for M365 to work
Last week I moved domain to a different AWS account (say AWSY). This means our NS and SOA are not the same anymore from M365's perspective.
We have added MX, TXT and CNAME to AWSY, however M365 is still trying to validate with NS and SOA of AWSX.
I cannot determine where to change NS & SOA in M365.
Our emails have stopped working due to this!! Help is much appreciated.


Describe more in detail what you have done, where the domain is hosted, what you would like the values to be, and what they are. Also tell us the domain. Do not redact it.

I have changed AWS servers. This means the NS and SOA are not the same anymore. - That sentence by itself makes no sense. What does AWS have to do with your name servers? We can infer what you're implying, but you need to gives us more detail on what it is that you did, and give us the domain name so we can help.

Hi, please let us know the default TTL you had on these entries too, as it might impact when Microsoft will re-dig your zone

Thanks. I've amended the description and hopefully it give more clarity. TTL is 3600

The Route53 bug prevented the propogation and AWS support helped fix the issue.
Once this was fixed, Microsoft 365 picked up new name servers automatically. The documentation suggested to use @ as the host name while configuring MX and TXT. Don't do this, leave it empty.
Thank you all for extending your support on this.
